# How to auto create a folder when I register a user

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

How can I create a new folder in storage for every user I register in my app?

Code user

```
 Future resUer() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _gmailController.text,
        password: _contrasenaController.text).then(FirebaseStorage.instance.);

    addUser(_usuarioController.text, _gmailController.text, _contrasenaController.text);

  }
```

Method to implement to my code

Comment: Firebase Storage [doesn't really have folders](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders).  Those things that look like folders are actually just the "prefix" of a path where an object lives.  You can upload an object whenever you want with whatever prefix you want any time you want - there is no need to create a "folder" to contain objects.